# Evaluating expression inside angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I want my table to conditionally render its row based on whether the value is null or not. The rows have different custom entries and labels, that's why I can't just use ng-repeat. Here's the code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-show = "{{data.entry_1}} !== null">
            <td>Custom Label 1</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_1}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show = "{{data.entry_2}} !== null">
            <td>Custom Label 2</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_2}}</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        <tr ng-show = "{{data.entry_n}} !== null">
            <td>Custom Label n</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_n}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it seems that this way is not right. It's either javascript (compiler) is complaining at {{}} in the ng-show or at '!== null' or maybe both. How to evaluate an angular expression (in {{}}) inside an *ng-* directive?

I know that I could also evaluate this instead in the js file, but since I don't want to add further scope variables (to make my code cleaner), I chose to evaluate if it is null in the ng-show directive. Could someone tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using the expression language in a wrong way, null condition should be inside the expression, i.e. `{{data.entry_2 !== null}}` Btw you can still use ng-repeat in tr and render the row conditionally if the custom entities have an index as given in your example. For example {{data['entry_' + ($index + 1)] !== null}} can make your code concise. But of course if the attributes have random names this approach won't work.

Comment: there is no need for {{}} in ng-show, you can do this with a function. e.g ng-show='calculate(0)' returning true or false. Think about reusable code so you don't need to repeat !== null every time and you can easily change the null to false for example if your scenario changes

Comment: @cubbuk It's wierd. When I use `ng-show = "false"`, chrome dev tools show another attribute `display: none`. If it's just `<tr ng-show="{{data.entry_i !== null}}">` still evaluates to true and `display: none` is gone, eventhough entry_i is not assigned any value in js file (the variable actually should not exist).

Comment: @Stefanos is right in ng-show you don't even need `{{}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The curly braces are only needed to echo/print/render the value of the variable. In an expression you should never use the curly braces.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app ng-init="data = {entry_1: 'notnull', entry_2: null, entry_n: 'againNotNull'}">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-show="data.entry_1">
            <td>Custom Label 1</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_1}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="data.entry_2">
            <td>Custom Label 2</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_2}}</td>
        </tr>
        .
        .
        .
        <tr ng-show="data.entry_n">
            <td>Custom Label n</td>
            <td>{{data.entry_n}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="data.device">
            <td>Custom Device</td>
            <td>{{data.device}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Another question, if, let's say variable 'device', was never a value of data, because the javascript file did not assign or initialize such variable to data (i.e., device does not exist in data), is it sufficient to compare `data.device !== null` to get "truthiness" or "falseyness"?

Comment: I have updated my example include this question. I would recommend reading the documentation on Angular Expressions. You do not need to evaluate "data.device !== null". "data.device" is sufficient. NG Expressions are much more forgiving than JS. If the property is undefined, or a parent object is undefined, the expression will be evaluated to false.

Answer (score -2):

Use $compile service in the context of the scope inside your directive.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Edit: I agree with Martin's answer.

Comment: I think this is a little overkill given the problem. In case of dynamically loaded DOM, maybe.

Comment: Creating a directive to evaluate an expression is counterproductive. The ngShow directive is sufficient.